# How do I implement a custom transition for a View in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to implement a transition that makes my view move in from the side an disappear by getting smaller. Apple already provides some Transitions but how can I customize this transitions? P.S. I am using the `.transition` modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a computed variable of the type `AnyTransition` as follows:

```
static var moveAndFade: AnyTransition {
    let insertion = AnyTransition.move(edge: .trailing)
        .combined(with: .opacity)
    let removal = AnyTransition.scale
        .combined(with: .opacity)
    return .asymmetric(insertion: insertion, removal: removal)
}
```

You might wanna check out the [tutorial series](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions) by Apple

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that there's a bug about the transition animations. You are supposed to be able to get what you want this way:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showView = false

    private var slideAndScale: AnyTransition {
        let insertion = AnyTransition.move(edge: .trailing)
        let removal = AnyTransition.scale
        return .asymmetric(insertion: insertion, removal: removal)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green
            if showView {
                Color.yellow
                    .transition(slideAndScale)
            }            
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showView.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                self.showView ? Text("HIDE VIEW") : Text("SHOW VIEW")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where the `Color.yellow` is the view that navigates in and out with the custom animation. But if you copy-paste this code you'll find out that the removal animation (in this case the scale animation) won't work. And this is a bug of `SwiftUI`. To solve this issue there's a workaround:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showView = false

    private var slideAndScale: AnyTransition {
        let insertion = AnyTransition.move(edge: .trailing)
        let removal = AnyTransition.scale
        return .asymmetric(insertion: insertion, removal: removal)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green
            VStack {
                if showView {
                    Color.yellow
                        .transition(slideAndScale)
                }
            }
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showView.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                self.showView ? Text("HIDE VIEW") : Text("SHOW VIEW")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

embed the `if showView` block in a `VStack` and the removal animation will behave as expected.